# Enable/Disable Button based on selected value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a button in my view

```
<v-menu offset-y>
  <v-btn>
    Action Items
  </v-btn>
  <v-list>
   <v-list-tile
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="index"      
   :disabled="item.disabled"
  >
   <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
   </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
 </v-menu>

<v-data-table
         v-model="selected">
```

my data looks like

```
<script>

    export default {
        data: () => ({
            selected: [],
            items: [
                { title: 'Delete',disabled:false},
            ],
...
```

i am trying to enable or disable the `v-list-tile` based on whether the `selected` array has any values.

i tried something like:

```
items: [
                { title: 'Delete',disabled:this.selected.length=0},
            ],
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "selected" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Computed property might be ideal in this situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say rather than have a `disabled` property on your model, you can have it as a computed property like so:

```
computed: {
    disabled() {
        return this.selected.length < 1; // or === 0   
    }
}
```

Then use the `disabled` property in your component.

```
<v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in items"
   :key="index"      
   :disabled="disabled">

    <v-list-tile-title>
       {{ item.title }}
    </v-list-tile-title>

</v-list-tile>
```

> PS: that props is passed into your `v-list-tile` as disabled property of that element. I am not sure if a custom component will be disabled (otherwise you know you'll use it on a real html element)

Comment: Hey, buddy,

I created similar logic, but my `disabled()` method is a normal one, not computed. I have a checkbox that must enable/disable a v-select. I do it as follows: `<v-select :disabled="disableSelect(i)"></v-select>`. However, for some reason the `disableSelect` method is called only initially, whenever I change the checkbox, it is not fired.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is that when the component is rendered the method is called. But instead you should attach it to an event e.g @changed event. You need to check v-select docs on which event is emitted when the item is changed.